# How might "a linear mapping is its own differential" be stated better?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, definition, vector-fields

This is Example II-2.3 of https://www.scribd.com/read/282634061/Advanced-Calculus-of-Several-Variables?mode=standard

> If $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is *linear*, then $F$ is differentiable everywhere, and
> $$dF_\mathbf{a}=F\text{ for all } \mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n,$$
> In short, a linear mapping is its own differential, because
> $$\lim_{\mathbf{h}\to\mathbf{0}}\frac{F\left(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{h}\right)-F\left(\mathbf{a}\right)-F\left(\mathbf{h}\right)}{\left|\mathbf{h}\right|}=\lim_{\mathbf{h}\to\mathbf{0}}\frac{\mathbf{0}}{\left|\mathbf{h}\right|}=\mathbf{0}$$
> by linearity of $F$.

When I encountered that, I was baffled by it.  It's typically difficult to explain confusion after the fact, but here is an attempt.  Consider the linear mapping

$$F_{\mathbf{x}}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)=\vec{m}\cdot\mathbf{x}.$$

I was thinking,  well, what about something like

$$F_{\mathbf{x}}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)^{\prime}=\left(\vec{m}\cdot\mathbf{x}\right)^{\prime}=\vec{m}^{\prime}\cdot\mathbf{x}+\vec{m}?$$

It took me a long time to sort out what Edwards was intending by the above example.

Here's what I believe to be a more complicated instance of the same difficulty:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/528210/117014

**How might Edwards's example be better stated, without being too sophisticated?**

There is certainly a chance that I missed something obvious in his material leading up to the example, or that my thinking wasn't logical.  But I doubt I am the only person to stumble on this or similar situations.

Perhaps the following will better explain the source of my confusion. This is the context I am accustomed to when considering linear mappings at a point. Note that the mapping itself is a function of position. [https://www.amazon.com/Theoretical-Physics-Dover-Books/dp/0486652270](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486652270)

[image]

And to clear up any misconceptions regarding my respect for Edwards's book, this is my copy.
[image]

Comment: Your computation is just incorrect. I'll let other people explain in details, but at least consider this as an intuitive explanation: the differential of $F$ at $a$ is the linear function which approximates $F$ the best around $a$. So when $F$ is already linear, obviously the best approximation is itself.

Comment: The 1-dimension version says: the derivative of $ax$ is $a$ at every point.   In this case, we want: the differential of $F(x)$ is $F$ at every point.

Comment: There is mistake in your definition of differential. Should be F(a+h)-F(a)

Comment: @CaptainLama My counterexample isn't very good.  My point is that a linear mapping can be a function of position.  That's what a differential form is.

Comment: @Surb Thanks.  That's why I prefer $\Delta{\mathbf{x}}$ to $\mathbf{h}$

Comment: It really is stated with perfect clarity. You should turn some of your accusatory tone to yourself. The computation you quoted is also misquoted by you.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I did acknowledge that the difficulty could be on my end.  It appears you missed my point, and the source of my confusion.  The equation isn't from Edwards.  It was intended to explain my confusion.  That is, the mapping itself might be a function of position.  For example, a velocity field.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin you may want to ask yourself why someone else was able to immediately understand my question, and provide an answer in the language of continuum mechanics.

Comment: I'm just complaining about the tone. If $F(x)=m(x)\cdot x$ and $m$ is not a constant, then this is *not* a linear function of $x$. So you need to use the chain rule here to reduce to the case of a linear map. My complaint about the misquote is that you left out the most important term in the limit computation. As it stands, the limit that you wrote down does not even exist.

Comment: I didn't notice I had done that.  Thank you.  As I said.  It's often difficult to explain confusion after the fact.  I had no one to consult when studying the book.  The definition of differentiability, and thereby, the implicit definition of the derivative were new to me.  I did not intend to disparage Edwards's book.  It is true that I was baffled by the idea that the differential was a constant linear mapping at a point for a long time.   It probably didn't help that the demonstration came in an example, rather than a corollary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a differentiable map, then its differential is a map:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}f : \mathbb{R}^n &\to L\left(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m\right) \\
x & \mapsto \mathrm{d}_xf
\end{align}
Hence, $\mathrm{d}f$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$. It does not have sense to say "$f$ is equal to its own differential $\mathrm{d}f$": these two functions do not live in the same space.

But if $f$ is linear, what is true is that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $\mathrm{d}_xf = f$. This is because:
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \forall h \in \mathbb{R}^n, f(x+h) = f(x) + f(h)
$$
and consequently
$$
f(x+h) = f(x) + f(h) + o(\|h\|)
$$
and the very definition of the differential of $f$ at $x$ is the only linear map $\mathrm{d}_xf$ such that:
$$
f(x+h) = f(x)+ \mathrm{d}_xf(h) + o(\|h\|)
$$
Hence, what makes sense is saying "$\mathrm{d}f$ is a constant map and at each point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathrm{d}_xf = f$". An analogy can be made with linear maps on $\mathbb{R}$, that is if $f(x) = ax$. Then $f'$ is a constant map, with $f'(x)=a$.

Comment: One could also use the short form in the quote provided, adding one brief phrase: "At each point, a linear mapping is its own differential".

Comment: @Didier The only problem with what you posted is that the concepts used are too anvanced for that part of the book.

Comment: Being a $o(\|h\|)$ is the very same definition (~ish) as saying dividing by $\|h\|$ makes something that goes to zero, if that is what you are suggesting with the term "being too avanced"

Comment: BTW: in Edwards's book, $\mathrm{d}_xf$ is a *partial differential*  of $f$ with respect to $x$.  Whereas $\mathrm{d}f_x$ is the differential of $f$ at $x$.  So $\mathrm{d}_xf$ removes the ambiguity I was confused by, but is introduced much later.

Comment: $\mathrm{d}_xf$, $\mathrm{d}f_x$ or $\mathrm{d}f(x)$ are just notations. What matters is how we define it: here, I said it is the differential, not a partial derivative (which is, btw, usually denoted by $\partial_xf$)